# React JS: Reusable components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have created the form validation with a structure like this

```
var Signin = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        return (
                <Form>
                    <Input type="text" name="email" labelName="Email" rules="isEmail" error:"Email not valid" />
                    <Input type="password" name="password" labelName="Password" rules="isLength:6" error:"Passowrd not valid"/>
                </Form>
        );
    }
});
```

because, for example, the "Email" input will be used in different part of application, I would avoid to add  the same attributes (name, type, labelName, rules and error) every time. So I would create something like this

```
var InputEmail = React.createClass({

    render: function () {

        return (
            <Input type="text" name="email" labelName="Email" rules="isEmail" error="Email not valid"/>
        )
    }
});

var InputPassword = React.createClass({

    render: function () {

        return (
            <Input type="password" name="password" labelName="Password" rules="isLength:6" error="Passwordnot valid"/>
        )
    }
});
```

So the Signin Component should be

```
var Signin = React.createClass({

    render: function() {

        return (
                <Form>
                    <InputEmail />
                    <InputPassword />
                </Form>
        );
    }
});
```

but in this way, I get two errors:

1. I can't find anymore in the Form the props.name of Input because
   there isn't in InputEmail;
2. in the render function of Input the state is null

How could I create a reausable/inherits components? I failed using both the composition pattern and the mixins

I added  my full code: Form

```
var Form = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            isValid : false,
            isSubmitting: false
        }
    },

    componentWillMount: function(){
        this.model = {};
        this.inputs = {};
        this.registerInputs(this.props.children);

    },

    registerInputs: function(children){


        React.Children.forEach(children, function (child) {


            if (child.props.name) {


                child.props.attachToForm = this.attachToForm;

                child.props.detachFromForm = this.detachFromForm;

                child.props.validate = this.validate;
            }
            if (child.props.children) {
                this.registerInputs(child.props.children);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },


    attachToForm: function (component) {
        this.inputs[component.props.name] = component;
        this.model[component.props.name] = component.state.value;
        this.validate(component);
    },

    detachFromForm: function (component) {
        delete this.inputs[component.props.name];
        delete this.model[component.props.name];
    },

    validate: function (component) {

        var isValid = true;
                // validation code
        component.setState({
            isValid: isValid,

        }, this.validateForm);

    },


    validateForm: function () {
        var formIsValid = true;

        var inputs = this.inputs;
        Object.keys(inputs).forEach(function (name) {
            if (!inputs[name].state.isValid) {
                formIsValid = false;
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            isValid: formIsValid
        });
    },

    updateModel: function (component) {
        Object.keys(this.inputs).forEach(function (name) {
            this.model[name] = this.inputs[name].state.value;
        }.bind(this));
    },

    submit: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            isSubmitting : true
        });

        this.updateModel();
        console.log(this.model);
    },

    render: function () {

        return (

            <form className="ui form" onSubmit={this.submit}>
                {this.props.children}
                <button className="ui button" type="submit" disabled={this.state.isSubmitting}>Accedi</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

Input

```
var Input = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            value : this.props.value || "",
            isValid: true
        }
    },

    setValue: function (event) {

        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value
        }, function () {

            this.props.validate(this);

        }.bind(this));
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {

        if (this.props.required) {
            this.props.validations = this.props.validations ? this.props.validations + ',' : '';
            this.props.validations += 'isLength:1';
        }

                // ERROR: TypeError: this.props.attachToForm is not a function
        this.props.attachToForm(this);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        this.props.detachFromForm(this);
    },


    render: function () {

        var className = "field";

        if(this.props.className){
            className +=  " " + this.props.className;
        }

        if(this.props.required){
            className += " required";
        }

        var Label;
        if(this.props.labelName){
            Label = (<label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.labelName}</label>);
        }

        var Error;
        if(!this.state.isValid){
            Error = (<div className="ui">{this.props.error || this.props.name + " not valid"}</div>);
        };


        return (
            <div className={className}>
                {Label}
                <input type={this.props.type || "text"} id={this.props.name} name={this.props.name} onChange={this.setValue} value={this.state.value} />
                {Error}
            </div>
        );

    }
});
```

With this works

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Form>
        <Input type="text" name="email" labelName="Email" rules="isEmail" error:"Email not valid"/>
    </Form>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

In this way I get: 
"TypeError: this.props.attachToForm is not a function
this.props.attachToForm(this);"

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Form>
        <InputEmail/>
    </Form>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

P.S: I tried to add this code on jsfiddle but I get "!TypeError: can't define property "attachToForm": Object is not extensible"

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acn8u7jr/)

Comment: One suggestion here is to not use a separate component to encapsulate the reusable behaviour. You could instead create an object that represents the props you want to reuse then spread them into your inputs that need them `var inputEmailProps = {  }, <Input { ...inputEmailProps } />`

Comment: It's important to note for people trying to help you solve this what other libs your using; it looks like you're using React-bootstrap, right? Make sure to note that, as those APIs are part of the question

Comment: @markthethomas I'm using semantic ui and validator's module for the form validation

Comment: But for the components `Input`, `Form`, etc., where do they come from? Capitalized components are customer, lower-case are native, so it appears you're using a library that provides some custom components. Are those also from semantic UI? Thanks!

Comment: No library.  I've created my custom components following this link http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2014/10/22/nailing-that-validation-with-reactjs.html

Comment: Can you share more relevant code for us to help? You get errors in code you did not share: state is null in `<Input>` . Where is your code for this `<Input>`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean with "I can't find anymore in the Form the props.name of Input because there isn't in InputEmail". What is the error you get? In which component? In your before as well as after-example, `<Form>` does not receive any props. In the code you shared, there does not appear to be a prop issue.

Comment: @wintvelt: I added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 main issues with your setup:

1. Your `<Form>` is set up in such a way, that the children of the form need to have props, otherwise it does not work.
2. The `<InputEmail>` wrapper is incomplete. It needs to pass along all props to the `<Input>`, including the Form functions passed down.

**Ad 1: Fix the form, to ensure validation methods are added**
The reason you get the error is because the children of your `<Form>` need to have props.name. It then registers the functions of the form (including attachToForm), by adding them to the children. This is done in the method `registerInputs()`.

In the original variant, the `<Input>` component has props, so all goes well.

In the adapted variant, the wrapper `<InputEmail>` no longer has props, so the `attachToForm()` and other functions are not added to props, and you get the error when the `<Input>` tries to invoke the function.

Simplest way to fix this: add at least 1 prop in the render function, and check this in the `registerInputs()`, e.g.:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Form>
        <InputEmail initialValue={'name@domain.com'}/>
    </Form>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And in `registerInputs()`, change the line:

```
if (child.props.name) {
```

to:

```
if (child.props.initialValue) {
```

**2. Extend `<InputEmail>` wrapper to pass down functions as well**
Simplest way to do this is to add `{...this.props}`, like this:

```
var InputEmail = React.createClass({

    render: function () {

        return (
            <Input {...this.props}
              type="text" name="email" labelName="Email" rules="isEmail" error="Email not valid"/>
        )
    }
});
```

That way, the functions passed down by `<Form>` to the `<InputEmail>` component (as well as any other props), will be passed down to the `<Input>` component.

PS: The code inside `registerInputs()` that checks for child.props.children does not work as intended: at the time it is invoked, the `<InputEmail>` component does not have children. Like the name implies, it checks for children passed down as props. And the only prop passed was `initialValue`.

As minor issues I would suggest to make 2 more changes:

3. In `registerInputs()`, you directly modify props. This is generally not a good idea. Better is to make a copy of props, and add your form-methods to the copy. You can use `React.Children.map` to do this. See [official docs here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.map).
4. Instead of hard-coding the `name="email"` etc of your `<Input>` component, inside `<InputEmail>`, better is to put the default values of these in default values of props, using `propTypes`, as explained [here in official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation).

Comment: Thanks. You wrote " There are 2 MAIN..." , what would be the other minor issues?

Comment: Updated answer with suggestions for minor issues too.